# Suggestions on how to parse a csv with tree nodes

Tags: python, pandas, tree

I've been spending way too many hours working on a problem and my coworker suggested I post here asking for suggestions for a tree node/leaf problem. I'm working in python libtree and pandas. Currently, I have a single CSV file with over 450,000 leaf nodes, a single leaf per line. The parenting is all in one column in the format 'Parent -->' per parent above the leaf. Not sure if this is a common format, but it's easy to parse.

​An example of the parenting column for a leaf node 4 layers down would be "Node A --> Node AA --> Node AAB"

Resolving to:

```
Root
 |
 +---> Node A
        |
        +---> Node AA
               |
               +---> Node AAB
                      |
                      +---> Leaf
```

​The kicker is, my team needs to get this data imported into an off-site WebGUI. The WebGUI system has a limited CSV import feature and does allow us to move parent folders around via drag and drop after importing. It also has the following restrictions.

​1) The number of leaf nodes per CSV files with less than 8000 leaf nodes, so the CSV needs to be broken down into segments.

​2) Every import will create a new tree off of the root, no merging. If it exists the import will create a new node and append a generated UUID to the new node name.

​Example If you attempt to import a new CSV file with a leaf node of "Node A --> Node AA --> Node AAC", you would see:

```
 Root
     |
     +---> Node A
     |      |
     |      +---> Node AA
     |             |
     |             +---> Node AAB
     |                    |
     |                    +---> Leaf
     +---> Node A-d8c0b6b8-728a-11e9-8848-1681be663d3e
            |
            +---> Node AA
                   |
                   +---> Node AAC
                          |
                          +---> Leaf
```

The best solution for this I can come up with for this so far to handle our large CVS file is:

- Break the file down into segments starting at farthest branches down the tree walking backwards till I have 7999 leaf nodes.
- Write out a new CVS file with the top node with an easy to handle name identifying the parent node this should be imported to.
- Have an Intern drag and drop the folders using the WebGUI to the correct locations.

​I'm a stubborn admin who does a bit script monkey work and I'm finding this a bit beyond my experience level. Please let me know if I am missing something obvious. I would like to resolve this in python 2.7x or 3.x to check in at work.

​I originally posted this to Reddit /r/LearningPython channel so you may have seen this question before. Please let me know if there is a better area, site.
​
Thanks for any suggestions or help.